# How to keep ID of post in state when opening a link in a new tab in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm building react website which topic is Blogging... I made it to work, and i can open a link in the same tab, but when i go and open link in another tab, or just paste link of post in the url, in some another tab, i get that message that my ID is undefined, which is obvious because my state is null. Here's how my link looks like

```
const TitleLink = (props) => ( <h1 className="post-title"><Link to={{pathname: "/posts/"+props.titleSplited, state:{id:props.id}}} > {props.title} </Link></h1> );
```

and in page where i'm showing full post i get my id like this

```
var id = this.props.location.state.id;
```

And it works great until i open it in a new tab or paste post url in another tab. I tried with pushState, but again it wont work, so now i dont know what to do... It was working while i was passing ID of a post through URL, but i removed it because i dont want ugly URL, i want that my url looks like

```
http://mywebsite.com/posts/this-is-just-a-spam
```

and not

```
http://mywebsite.com/posts/83hjdjadt2642djxa/this-is-just-a-spam
```

only mutual thing i can get is title, so i thought to make a hidden field which will contain ref like this-is-just-a-spam and its value would be post id. I don't know is it good idea or not, i'm stucked with this already 3 days and i cant find solution... I would be very grateful if you could help me. Thanks

Comment: What is your backend? You could rewrite URLs if you don't want ugly ones. But anyway, if you load post you need to have some mechanism to know which post to load (that is porpuse of ID of the post in your URL)

Comment: my backend is Express... i can do that but i thought it has to be some better solution... @VladoPandžić ... it is probably better that hidden field, dont know

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace ?

Comment: and what if i come to site, copy this replaced url _http://mywebsite.com/posts/this-is-just-a-spam_ and send to you? will your browser still know that there is ID hidden? i guess not, and then post id will still be undefined @VladoPandžić

Comment: yes, it will be undefined, this just replaces url to make it pretty while in search bar :)